# autocomplete='off' functionality for a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using divs to hold all inputs. When I refresh <kbd>F5</kbd> in Firefox values that were entered (but not saved) remains on the form.

How do I force all inputs to be empty when they are really empty after page refresh?

A solution would be `autocomplete='off'`, but it's good only for a form.

Is there a similar functionality when a div is holding the input elements?

A HTML, JavaScript or jQuery solution would be ok.

EDIT:
Also another solution could be applying autocomplete='off' to all inputs but I think this is not an elegant solution..

Comment: I did not downvoat your answer... I placed an EDIT

Comment: Why did you rollback an edit that cleaned up your post?

Comment: Sorry, come again? I just asked a question. Let's not be rude.

Comment: @ihtus : Did you got the solution or still in problem .. please share your thought.

Comment: @Rubyist: see comment for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `autocomplete="off"` property for each input.

Comment: Appears to be only way

Answer (score 0):

While loading of page, just put inside the document.ready statement of jquery

```
$('#<form_id>')[0].reset();
```

Example :

```
<script type="javascript">
  $(function() {
     $('#<form_id>')[0].reset();  

  });
</script>
```

Just try this at your html page.

```
<div class="test_value"> Test </div>
<div class="test_value"> asdfTest </div>
<div class="test_value"> Tes asd fast </div>
<div class="test_value"> Testa dfasdf </div>

$(function(){
       $('.test_value').text('');
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D3prt/347/)

Comment: thank you, but I guess this works for <form id='form_id'>, I don't have forms, only divs.

Comment: Let me try again for this ... Can you post your div inside your question or jsfiddle anything

Comment: that works only for <form>. See this (not mine, edited) http://jsfiddle.net/8zLLn/142/

Comment: do you think $('.test_value').text(''); is relevand to my question?

Comment: You have to put some class to your div to make it empty while reloading Or share that snippet of code so that we can try some thing on that.